# Conditions of use of ようでは as "if"

Tags: grammar, nuances

ようでは is translated is "if", but I would like to know the conditions of use of ようでは (ie when it is appropriated to use it).
I have some sentences:

> こんな簡単な問題が解決できない**ようでは**、困る。 
>   We’ll be in big trouble if we can’t solve such
>   a simple problem.
>
> これぐらいの困難にぶつかって落ち込む**ようでは**何事もできない。 
>   If I feel upset after facing such a
>   small obstacle, I won’t be able to do anything.

Could you tell me more about the pattern ようでは  (and on a side note, where does this structure come from) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, ようでは expresses "if (this negative situation is the case), then ...".

There is a good explanation of this on p725 of A Dictionary of Advanced Grammar. In case you don't have access to that, their definition is:

> "a conjunction that presents an undesirable situation, which is assumed to be factual"

Examples:
成績が今までのようでは、困ります。
If your performance is like what it has been up to now, it's a problem.

アパートがそんなに高いようでは私たちは東京には住めない。
If apartments in Tokyo are that expensive, we can't live there.

You can check out lots of other sample sentences [here](https://jn1et.com/youdeha/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and thank for the book reference too !

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: How is this different from ては? 計画が敵に知られては、せっかくの苦心も水の泡だ

Comment: Apparently, ようでは and ては are very similar, but according to same source, ては is more direct.